# Styled Components TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Using `styled-components`, with normal React.js I can do like:

```
const Container = styled.div({
  userSelect: `none !important`,
})
```

however with TypeScript I get the error:

```
Argument of type '{ userSelect: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userSelect' does not exist in type 'TemplateStringsArray'.ts(2345)
```

What's the best way to fix this?

I don't want to use the `styled.div` template strings approach as I find it a lot less flexible.

For example with template strings we can't do things like:

```
const flex = {
  flex: display: flex,
  col: flexDirection: `column`
}

const FlexRow = styled.div({
  ...flex.flex,
})

const FlexCol = styled.div({
   ...flex.flex,
   ...flex.col,
})
```

Comment: What `styled` library are you using? Could you please provide a link to its docs or NPM package.

Comment: Oops sorry. Added now.

Comment: And again some ts types are not accurate ...

Comment: Why you are using a template string if there is no variable inside? Why not just normal string? Or that was just an example?

Comment: If you mean in the `Container`, it shouldn't make a difference. I prefer backticks to single quotes. Also it's just an example :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** On further investigation, it appears that @Vincent was on the right track before I figured out what was actually going on.

```
import styled, { CSSObject } from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div({
  userSelect: "none !important"
} as CSSObject);
```

Will generate the following error:

```
Conversion of type '{ userSelect: "none !important"; }' to type 'CSSObject' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ userSelect: "none !important"; }' is not comparable to type 'Properties<string | number>'.
    Types of property 'userSelect' are incompatible.
      Type '"none !important"' is not comparable to type '"contain" | "all" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "auto" | "none" | "text" | "-moz-none" | "element" | undefined'.ts(2352)
```

So yes, styled components does indeed support this syntax even in TypeScript, it just doesn't understand the `!important` suffix. Here's a slightly modified solution you might prefer:

```
const important = <T extends string>(s: T): T => `${s} !important` as T;

const Container = styled.div({
  userSelect: important("none"),
});
```

It's a little hacky (casting `"none !important"` as `"none"` when it clearly isn't), but it keeps your styled CSS props clean and passes the type-checks.

---

**Original Answer:** I'm not familiar with that syntax for styled components (it looks a bit like JSS, but not exactly).

I'd recommend using the standard syntax. Styled components are usually written like this:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  user-select: none !important;
`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not a fan of that syntax since I can't just merge style objects in, which is annoying.

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks. I'll see if I can work that into my answer.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for the comprehensive answer. And thanks to @Vincent too!

Answer (score 5):

it doesn't recognize the `!important` so just cast it to any to quiet typescript.

```
styled.div({
  userSelect: 'none !important'  as any
});
```

#### EDIT - explanation of why this works

its very simple. if you use an ide like atom you can "go to" the type for the userSelect property. The type is `UserSelectProperty` and its value must be one of these exactly.

```
export type Globals = "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset";
export type UserSelectProperty = Globals | "-moz-none" | "all" | "auto" | "contain" | "element" | "none" | "text";
```

Since `none !important` is not an option, you have to cast it to any.

Comment: Probably Typescript will need some string literal type compose syntax ... :)

Comment: Huh, this actually fixes the error. Can you explain what's going on here please?

Comment: @Vencovsky the same error happens with "normal" strings.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this question while looking for something slightly related. I know it's resolved but I've used styled-components for quite a while and never have happened to see the object syntax you refer to, I presume this is included to allow adoption from other css-in-js options.

However, the reason for me commenting is your flex example, you could achieve a very similar effect with tagged template literals:

```
const flex = {
  flex: 'display: flex',
  col: 'flex-direction: column'
}

const FlexRow = styled.div`
  ${flex.flex};
`

const FlexCol = styled.div`
  ${flex.flex};
  ${flex.col};
`
```

Happy styled-componenting

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- I know, I prefer the object notation for two reasons. 1.) I find it much easier to create mix-ins for commonly-used combinations, and 2.) Because you can merge style objects together.